# Using a function to set log file id with snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I would like to use a function to set output log file names easily.

I tried the following function

```
# output_path=simulations/sim1/model/test.out
# idx=2   == add <x> after 2nd element
# x=logs
# returns= simulations/sim1/logs/model/test.out
def get_xpath(wildcards,x,idx):
  outbase=wildcards.output[0]
  return str('/'.join(outbase.split('/')[:idx])+"/"+x+"/"+'/'.join(outbase.split('/')[idx:]))

rule testme:
...
  log: lambda wildcards: get_xpath(wildcards,"logs",2),
```

But it gives the following AttributeError

```
'function' object has no attribute 'get_wildcard_names'
```

I also tried using lambda:

```
rule testme:
...
  log: lambda wildcards, output: output[0].split('.')[0],
```

Which gives the same error. I could not find any examples to achieve this in the snakemake documentation, so I am not sure if this is even possible. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack only, but one way is to put this into the `params` directive. The advantage is that this will not be deleted if rule fails:

```py
rule abc:
    params: log = lambda wildcards: get_xpath(wildcards,"logs",2),
    ...
```

Of course, the references inside the executable (shell/run/script) would have to be adjusted to `params.log` rather than `log`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround.

You still cannot get the output file name without copying it manually, but you can use a function to make it easier to name log files by using rule names as variables. It can be improved by making use of certain wildcards or by providing a hard copy of the output filename. Though setting rule names as variables limits some functionality such as directly calling a rule by its name.

```py
def logfile(rule_name,wildcards=None,output=None):
    return f"{config['dataset_id']}/logs/{rule_name}.log"

ruleid="get_fasta_per_locus"
rule ruleid:
    input:
    output:
    log:
        lambda wildcards: logfile(ruleid)
```