# Snakemake overwrites rules' log files when using retries - idiomatic way to make it append?

Tags: logging, snakemake

I have a Snakemake workflow in which a rule can seemingly randomly fail. I'm using Snakemake 7.7.0 and have set retries for the rule using the `retries` directive. The command prints to stdout and stderr, and I want to append both to a logfile, keeping output from failed tries, so I can keep track of the failures. The simplified version of what I have is as follows:

```
rule flaky_rule:
    input:
        infile = "{sample}/foo.txt"
    output:
        outfile = "{sample}/bar.txt"
    retries: 3
    log:
        flaky_rule_log = "{sample}/logs/flaky_rule.log"
    shell:  
        """
        flaky_script -i "{input.infile}" -o "{output.outfile}" >> "{log.flaky_rule_log}" 2>&1 
        """
```

However, when I run this and the rule fails and is rerun, the logfile appears to be overwritten. For now, my workaround is to set the logfile in a `params` directive instead, but this of course will get me told off by the linter since I "don't have a logfile set" and feels a bit hackish to me. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this (either in this version or a higher one)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably too convoluted and not very idiomatic, but here's an option anyway. Run your command as a python subprocess, analysed the output and decide what to do after so many retries. For example:

```
rule flaky_rule:
    input:
        infile = "{sample}/foo.txt"
    output:
        outfile = "{sample}/bar.txt"
    params:
        retries = 3
    log:
        flaky_rule_log = "{sample}/logs/flaky_rule.log"
    run:
        import subprocess

        for retry in range(0, params.retries):
            p = subprocess.Popen('flacky_script {input} {output} >> "{log.flaky_rule_log}" 2>&1', 
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
            if p.returncode == 0:
                break
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise Exception('Failed after %s retries' % params.retries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation based on [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448228/10693596). The idea is to specify the path to the log file as a resource. This means that `snakemake` will not automatically clear it (which can be undesirable in some circumstances, so use with caution):

```py
rule flaky_rule:
    input:
        infile = "{sample}/foo.txt"
    output:
        outfile = "{sample}/bar.txt"
    resources:
        flaky_rule_log = lambda wildcards, attempt: f"{wildcards.sample}/logs/flaky_rule_attempt{attempt}.log"
    retries: 3        
    shell:  
        """
        flaky_script -i "{input.infile}" -o "{output.outfile}" >> "{resources.flaky_rule_log}" 2>&1 
        """
```

It would be great if `params` or `logs` supported `attempt`, but right now this is still [an open issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/499).